# spring: need for an example of using prototype bean in a web environment

Tags: spring

I wonder how can I properly inject a prototype bean to a singleton one in a web app. Consider this example:

```
<bean id="order" class="com.foo.Order" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="orderService" class="com.foo.OrderService">
    <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>
</bean>
```

I thought of using getBean() but isn't that a way to make my code dependent to spring itself?

I need a short java code example to demonstrate how to inject an order bean in my OrderService singleton.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jsr-330 [Providers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html), just put:

```
@Autowired
Provider<Order> orderProvider;
```

in your singleton bean, and then use the provider:

```
public Whatever yourMethod() {
     Order order = orderProvider.get();
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `Provider` :D Sadly lot's of people don't know about them

Comment: @RalfHoppen I discovered them quite recently (like two days ago) and found them very clean.

Comment: Like what @RalfHoppen said, I didn't know about it either. This is exactly what I needed.Thanks

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working as explained here. Please check my sample code given below.